# How to solve the error of "_OBJC_CLASS_$_PLCrashReport", referenced in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am creating an application in iphone in which I have imported a framework know as CrashReporter.Framework in my project. And I have imported this framework in my appdelegate and class named as CrashReportViewController.When I run the application it gives me the foll error:

```
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_PLCrashReport", referenced from:
objc-class-ref-to-PLCrashReport in WordPressAppDelegate.o
objc-class-ref-to-PLCrashReport in CrashReportViewController.o

"_OBJC_CLASS_$_PLCrashReporter", referenced from:
objc-class-ref-to-PLCrashReporter in WordPressAppDelegate.o
objc-class-ref-to-PLCrashReporter in CrashReportViewController.o
```

What may be the problem?

Comment: Did you read the relevant documentation on how to include this framework in your project? iOS can't use normal framework bundles at this time (either the full source has to be included, or you need to use a static library).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you actually linked the framework to your target application. In xcode 4, click the project file, click your desired target, select the build phases tab, expand link binary with libraries. If you do not see the framework you are trying to use, then click the plus at the bottom of that section navigate to the framework and add.

Answer (score 0):

I just caught the same problem, and struggled for 1 hour, and it turns out that the current stable version  1.0 of PLCrashReporter does not work with xcode 4.2. Need to use 1.1-rc1 instead.