# Linker id error

Tags: iphone

ld: duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_ASIFormDataRequest in /Users/masc/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Magyar_ujsagok-gsevookpjgregagahzlabjccbmuv/Build/Intermediates/Magyar ujsagok.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Magyar ujsagok.build/Objects-normal/i386/ASIFormDataRequest-36F91B6C474DB772.o and /Users/masc/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Magyar_ujsagok-gsevookpjgregagahzlabjccbmuv/Build/Intermediates/Magyar ujsagok.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Magyar ujsagok.build/Objec

Comment: please give me the answer

Comment: i think you have 2 files of ASIFormDataRequest in your code..check in your code my friend..Happy Coding!!!!

Comment: @user1947567 here two problem which give the error , first check that this file file may be 2 with same name in your project which NiravPatel says or otherwise some frameworks are missed so add these frmaework which i post in answer ..

Answer (score 1):

you got this Error becouse of missing some Framwork Adding in your Project while you Using `ASIHTTP`

**For ASIHTTP Request add the following frameworks:**

- libz.1.2.5.dylib
- SystemConfiguration
- UIKit
- Foundation
- CoreGraphics
- MobileCoreServices
- CFNetworks

If you are using ASIHttp classes in iOS 5 or later, you need to turn ARC off for the `ASIHttpRequest` classes in Project-> Build Phases -> Compile Sources by using `-fno-objc-arc` for the ASI API classes.

Answer (score 0):

Here 2 possibilities for this error ,

1. check that this file file may be 2 with same name in your project which NiravPatel says
2. otherwise some frameworks are missed so add these frmaework which i post bellow ..

just add following frameworks from `Build Phases=>Link Binaries with Libraries =>`

Add these following frameworks

[image: inclue]

Also see this answer which something related to your problem [How to solve the error of "_OBJC_CLASS_$_PLCrashReport", referenced in iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5561867/how-to-solve-the-error-of-objc-class-plcrashreport-referenced-in-iphone)

Comment: is it a memory related issue Bro..? mr.iPatel say's like that..

Comment: no its not the memory leak problem, but here some frameworks are missed which required for ASIHTTPRequest classes..

Comment: i just Conform that i knw that but i just ask you to mine answer is correct or my argument againts Mr.ipatel is right or not..? that's why

Comment: yes yes here this problem is may be with 2 files with same name is possible what say about it?? right??

Comment: yup...anyway weekend ahead hahah :)

Comment: yes bro... feel very nice now.. ;)